# how to vite inject css as http file during development rather inline style tag injection

Tags: css, inline, vite, inject

## Vite Bundler environment during development

Vite environment inject CSS into the page as inline:

`<style type="text/style"> //css code.. </style>`

how do i inject CSS into the page as a HTTP file instead?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="chunk-23dwdw.css">`

the idea is to make the file accessible for chrome development rather than inline code that is harder to debug.

Comment: I had the same issue today, have you found a way to solve this

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

try to make the CSS files inside the javascript file using `import`,

this will create a new file `.css` minified when deployed on production

```js
import css from "./style.css";
```

> for example vercel automatically does `npm run build`. and it will use the minified code. (dist/ folder)

---

❌ if you use `<style>` it won't be minified.

for example:

```html
<style>
#test {
  color: red
}
</style>
```

or

```html
<style>
@import url("./style.css");
</style>
```

it won't be minified (but if inside javascript yes)

---

- here how should be imported:
  [image]
- here vite create a CSS minified file after `npm run build` (not run dev):
  [image]
- here the CSS code is all in one line:
  [image]

Comment: sorry for the downvoting, if this isn't the answer that solves the problem, tell me so I will delete it (or improve it)

Comment: when you work in vite in dev mode. vite inject the CSS files as inline CSS. 
it means that you can't tell what the source/origin/source map of that css file. because it's inline. in other bundlers, they inject the CSS with the file CSS name as styyle-link-http file which means you can tell "oh, this CSS come from file Y.css"